# How to replace assert?

Tags: java, assertion

How can I replace assertions with `if`s? Example:

```
public Wezel<Wartosc,Indeks> getWujek() 
{
    assert rodzic != null; // Root node has no uncle
    assert rodzic.rodzic != null; // Children of root has no uncle
    return rodzic.getBrat();
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about it's semantic correctness, and i want to make it better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An assertion is roughly equivalent to:

```
if (!condition) {
    throw new AssertionError();
}
```

Comment: besides that assertions only work when the `-ea` switch is passed to the JVM

Comment: I suppose this answer is the best one, because i don't have to catch AssertionError().

Answer (score 2):

Replacing these assertions would take the form of the following validation:

```
if (rodzic == null)
   throw new MyValidationException("rodzic cannot be null");
if (rodzic.rodzic == null)
   throw new MyValidationException("rodzic.rodzic cannot be null");
return rodzic.getBrat();
```

Note that there's a distinction between throwing an `Exception` and an `Error` - `Exception`s are meant to be caught and handled farther up, while `Error`s indicate a situation that you can't recover from. For example, you might consider a defining and using a `MyValidationError` if the failed check is irrecoverable.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Wezel<Wartosc,Indeks> getWujek() 
    {
        if(rodzic == null) { // Root node has no uncle
            throw new Exception("Root node has no uncle");
        }
        if(rodzic.rodzic == null) {
            throw new Exception("Children of root have no uncle");
        }
        return rodzic.getBrat();
    }
```